# Definir el modelo User de Laravel con o sin confirmar registro

Tags: laravel, confirmar

Necesito para un proyecto Laravel poder definir el modelo `User` de modo dual, con o sin confirmación de registro. Me explico. En el archivo `.env` habrá una constante que determinará si se ha de enviar o no correo de confirmación de registro, algo así:

```
REGISTER_CONF=true
```

Si el valor es `true`, la clase del modelo `User` debería declararse así:

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerify
```

En cambio, si el valor en `.env` es `false`, debería declararse así:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
```

Es lo que, a priori, se me ocurre. Lo que necesito es que, en base al valor de `REGISTER_CONF` se necesite el correo de confirmación o no.

Comment: ¿Y por qué no mejor dejar desde el inicio que el modelo implemente esas interfaces, leer el valor de la variable y con base en un condicional determinar si es true o no y actuar en consencuencia?

Comment: Pero si implementas la interfaz, debes usarla, no? Ando un poco despistada, pero voy a probar que tal esa sugerencia. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Mucha razón @Laura1995 se me pasó ese detalle :(

Comment: Si trabajas con una lógica de MustVerify imagino que tendrás un middleware para sólo controlar a usuarios verificados en las peticiones, por qué no lo trabajas a nivel de middleware dependiendo de tu variable en el .env?